# Как вывести имена покупателей чей заказ отправлен после необходимой ( required ) даты?

Tags: sql, sql-server

дравствуйте!
у меня есть 2 таблицы - `Orders` , `Customers`
в `Orders` есть колонки `RequiredDate, ShippedDate`
в `Customers` колонка `ContactName`

мне нужно узнать имена тех , чьи заказы были отправлены после `RequiredDate`, на протяжении 1997г
Что у меня получилось: `Select distinct contactname,orderdate from customers left join orders on year(orderdate) = 1997`
как узнать чьи были отправлены после `RequiredDate`?

правильно ли будет после `.... on year(ordardate) = "1997"` добавить `where requireddate < shippeddate` ?

если да, то как дополнительно вывести общее число заказов отправленых не вовремя для каждого покупателя

Comment: Как связаны эти две таблицы? По какому полю?

Comment: @maxu customerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
select c.ContactName, count(*) as overdue_orders_no 
from Customers c
join Orders o
  on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where o.OrderDate >= cast('1997-01-01' as datetime)
  and o.OrderDate < cast('1998-01-01' as datetime)
  and o.ShippedDate > o.RequiredDate;
group by c.ContactName;
```

PS к SQL Server доступа у меня нет, поэтому протестировать этот код я не мог